# How do you calculate gas limit for transaction with data in Ethereum?

Tags: transactions, gas, gas-limit

What is the correct algorithm to calculate gas limit for transaction with data in Ethereum?

Comment: It's not a duplicate! The attached QA has nothing to do with arbitrary data cost estimation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [Ethereum Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), in order to calculate gas limit for transaction with non-zero data you will need to use the following formula:

> gasLimit = **G**<sub>transaction</sub> + **G**<sub>txdatanonzero</sub> **×** dataByteLength

where:

> **G**<sub>transaction</sub> = 21000 gas
>
> **G**<sub>txdatanonzero</sub> = 68 gas
>
> dataByteLength — your data size in bytes

So, the final formula would look like this:

`gasLimit = 21000 + 68 * dataByteLength`.

If your data has 10 bytes, the gas limit would be:

`gasLimit = 21000 + 68 * 10 = 21000 + 680 = 21680`

Comment: will it be different if I'm sending to a contract address?

Comment: How I can calculate dataByteLenght of my transaction?

Comment: Keep in mind if you're sending to a smart contract, that smart contract's internal functions will require additional gas depending on what all they do.

Comment: What's a reliable way to estimate the gas if we are calling a function on the smart contract? There is a `rpcProvider.estimateGas(txn)` method I can use, but it will fail to estimate the gas sometimes on some complicated functions

Comment: the answer should be outdated as of EIP-1559 release??